# exp@@glibc_2.2.5 undefined reference

Tags: ubuntu, natural-language, svm

I've been trying to use the SVM-python implementation provided at tfinley.net.

When I use the command make on the extracted directory,

```
/usr/bin/ld: svm_light/svm_common.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:92: recipe for target 'svm_python_learn_hideo' failed
make: *** [svm_python_learn_hideo] Error 1
```

this shows up. [This](http://tfinley.net/software/svmpython2/) is the implementation I am trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Add `LIBS=-lm` at the top of the MakeFile after export in order to link with the math library.

Comment: Why would this solve the issue?

Comment: I was forcing the implementation to work on Windows. I added additional batch scripts to get it work.
Apparently, it was not a good idea.
It worked perfectly on Linux.